# NoGray Time Picker conflict with Google Maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a page that has the NoGray Time Picker control on it and a Google map implementation. If I remove the NoGray Time Picker, the Google map works great (renders, shows map points, etc).  But when I include the NoGray Time Picker, I get the following javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'kc' of undefined
```

When I use Chrome to debug, it shows NoGray's extension to Function prototype at the base of the call stack.  And this error is occuring in Google api code...

Without giving away much of their code (but hopefully enough for anyone to find/reproduce)...I'm talking about the following in ng_all.js:

```
ng.extend_proto(Function, { set: function(
[...] //removed several lines
return a.apply(f, h.concat(d))
```

This all worked when first implemented but is now giving the error (without any code changes on our end), which causes the map to not render correctly (sometimes no map points, sometimes no map at all).  Any ideas?  Is there anyway to keep this prototype extension from affecting Google Map functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoGray is extending `Function.prototype`? Shame on them!

I looked at their code, and they add several methods to `Function.prototype`: `set`, `bind`, `delay`, `repeat`, `defer`, `inherit`, and `rename_method`.

The most worrisome is `Function.prototype.bind()`. Modern browsers already [have a `Function.prototype.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)! And it's not the same as the one NoGray is defining.

So any code that tries to use the standard `.bind()` will be broken when NoGray is included and it overwrites that method.

I don't know if that's what is breaking Google Maps, but it wouldn't surprise me at all.

The best solution here is to ditch this badly-behaved library and find another time picker that does not stomp on standard JavaScript methods like this.

If you want to try an experiment, though, you could do a search and replace and change all instances of `bind` in the NoGray code to `bindx` or something like that. That would avoid the conflict on the standard `.bind`, and if my theory is correct, it just might fix the bug.

Oh, wait. It gets worse. They are extending a bunch of other standard prototypes too! Besides `Function`, they also extend the prototypes for `RegExp`, `Array`, `String`, `Number`, and `Date`!!!

(This is the first time I've used "!!!" in a Stack Overflow answer, but it's well-deserved here.)

I don't have the patience to look through all the methods they are adding to those prototypes to look for potential conflicts, but if changing `bind` to `bindx` doesn't fix it, you could look through all of those other prototype extensions, find the MDN doc pages for each of those native objects, and see if there are any other standard methods they are overwriting.

Or, as I said earlier, just ditch this thing!

Comment: You were correct that it is the "bind" function that is causing the issue.  I contacted NoGray and they were able to give me a fix, which should be included in their next version.